# sorting 2d array using build in sort function

Tags: java, sorting

I was using Arrays.sort() function to sort 2d array (int[][] array). Since I want to sort it base on the first element. For example, {{2,3},{1,4}} base on 1st element the array will be {{1,4},{2,3}}. So I override the compare function.

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<int[]>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2){
        if(o1[0] < o2[0]){
            return -1;
        } else if (o1[0] > o2[0]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

})
```

I know this sort work. But I don't understand how this compare work. 
I was thinking the

```
new Comparator<int[]>
```

should be

```
new Comparator<int[][]>
```

since this is 2d array. and inside of compare function should be compare

```
o1[0][0]  and  o2[0][0]
```

Can anyone help me understand it?

Also this is using Arrays.sort, can I use Collections.sort? what is different between it?

Thanks

Comment: *FYI:* To get a compare value from comparing two `int` values, use `Integer.compare(o1[0], o2[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a "2D array" doesn't actually exist in Java, so what you're really dealing with is "an array of `int[]`" (there's nothing inherently preventing each of those `int[]` from being a different length).

So: when you sort, you're comparing individual elements of that "array of `int[]`" with each other, and because each element is an `int[]`, your Comparator is for `int[]`, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the array in the sort method and giving it a comparator. Arrays.sort will use iterator to pass into compare method. So compare method is checking element at arr[0].compare(arr[1]) sorts these 2 and goes to next iterator. same concept applies using 2d array. You are just passing 2 arrays and telling compare who should be placed where.